# Does google map geo location require secure ssl connection?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, ssl

I am using google map geo location api. I have first tested it on local, its working file on both firefox and chrome. When it moved it to live site (that is not https), its working fine for firefox but not working on chrome. Getting this error:

> Geocoder failed

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function successFunction(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function errorFunction() {
        alert("Geocoder failed");
    }
</script>
```

Does chrome need secure ssl connection for geo location??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Chrome version >= 50, Geolocation API requires secured origin. But, it should work fine on your localhost.

Secured origins are origins that match the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:

- (https, *, *)
- (wss, *, *)
- (*, localhost, *)
- (*, 127/8, *)
- (*, ::1/128, *)
- (file, *, —)
- (chrome-extension, *, —)

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en).

**Update:** Firefox, iOS Safari, Chrome Android, and Samsung Internet now also require secured contexts.

Comment: Fine. why its working on firefox? doesn't it require secure connection??

Comment: @MahaDev Only chrome who currently considers this geolocation as a powerful feature. Therefore they make it deprecated. **Others will follow**, there's a discussion that features such as *geolocation, notification, fullscreen, pointer lock and media stream APIs* will require secure origin in the future. So yeah, not yet for firefox.